# What's the use of generics constraints? for e.g: where T : IComparable

Tags: c#, generics

may hope, you all are well, I've some confusion about Constraint, i still don't get this, What's the benefit over using constraint?

I did understand tomorrow about `Generics`. It's an awesome features using this method, i mean that makes simplest way of using this, No need to make again and again method with different data types, simply you could call it with any types of Data type,

especially i did understand all those terms with that examples,

```
using System;

class Test<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public Test(T t)
    {
        this._value = t;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is {0}", this._value);
    }
}

class MyProgram
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test<int> test = new Test<int>(145);
        test.print();

        Test<string> test2 = new Test<string>("My name is ghost!");
        test2.print();

        Test<double> test3 = new Test<double>(458.5456);
        test3.print();
    }
}
```

But When i go deeply inside `Generics constraints`, i don't get this `What it is used for!`
Can you tell me with simplest example, What's the advantages over using this one?

I'm confused when i see this:

`public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:IComparable { }`

What is `where T:IComparable{}`?? what IComparable is defined?

thanks~

Comment: basically means where that class implements the IComparable interface

Comment: You should actually use `where T : IComparable<T>` instead of `where T : IComparable`, because the latter will lead to some unnecessary type checking, and (worse) boxing if `T` is (may be) a value type, i.e. a `struct` or an `enum`.

Comment: It effectively comes down to the same question as "Why use `IComparable x` and not `object x`?" (What can be done with `x` in either case?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without constraints, the lowest common type of `T` is `object`. Pretty useless if you want to do something common with a common set of types. By allowing constraints, you can "drag up" the lowest common type to that which you specified as the constraint. It also then stops you from using the generic code if you type does not meet the constraints.

`IComparable` will let your code call `CompareTo`, for example.

There are some other built in constraints available that are not related to your type hierarchy:

- `where T : class`
- `where T : struct`
- `where T : new()`

You can find out what these mean by [reviewing the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d5x73970.aspx).

---

`IComparable` is simply a .NET framework interface available in the BCL; [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value
>   type or class implements to order or sort its instances.

And as Jeppe Stig Nielsen has mentioned, you should use the generic version of `IComparable`, being `IComparable<T>`, on your generic constraint for various other benefits.

Comment: where T : class is important for using generics in Entity Framework, for example.

Comment: `the lowest common type of T is object` But here my `T` defines data type and yes, we could use here as `Test<int or string or whatever> test1=new Test<int or string or whatever>`. That makes an object as you mean! But `Pretty useless if you want to do something common with a common set of types.` But how it is pretty useless?? ..i still don't get you!

Comment: @reenakumar Instances of `T` will resolve to being the type you specify to close the generic, but when you try and use it, you will only get `object` members because that is all the compiler can give you, given that `T` could potentially be any type ever made. If all you are doing is exposing `T`, such as like `List<T>` then constraints are not required or have little benefit. I'm sorry, but I can't explain it any better than I have done.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are useful, because you demand the generic type you want to use to express some specific behavior, like implemenenting an interface as for your instance. This is a prerequisite for your case, because a tyope that implements this behaviour has some specific characteristics, that will be used in the generic class you declare.

Specifically, `IComparable`

> Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value type or class implements to order or sort its instances.

All the types that implement this interface, express the method called `CompareTo`, where

> Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance precedes, follows, or occurs in the same position in the sort order as the other object.

The signature of the method is:

```
int CompareTo(Object obj)
```

and returns

- *Less than zero*, This instance precedes obj in the sort order.
- *Zero*, This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as obj.
- *Greater than zero*, This instance follows obj in the sort order.

That being said, in your case, where the generic type you defined have to implement this behaviour, is required because in the definition of your type, you will need this method, `CompareTo`, which is implemented by types that implements the interface `IComparable`.

In another case, you might need your type would be only a `class`. Then the definition of your generic class would be:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T: class
```

On the other hand, in another case, you might need your type be only a `struct`. Then the definition of your type would be:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T: struct
```

Answer (score 0):

When use simple generics without any constraints, you can assume about generic type anything.

Consider the follwowing code:

```
class Test<T>
{
    public void Stuff()
    {
        T t;
        t = new T(); // COMPILE TIME ERROR - type T may not have a parameterless constructor
    }
}
```

With constraints:

```
class Test<T> where T : new()
{
    public void Stuff()
    {
        T t;
        t = new T(); // IT IS OK - the type T must have parameterless constructor.
    }
}
```

Consider helper class:

```
class A 
{
   public A(int a)
   {
   }
}
```

**When you will try to to compile `var test = new Test<A>();` you will get compile time error** (we are talking about Test with contraints of course) because type `A` doesn't contain parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:IComparable { }
```

then T has to implement the Interface IComparable! 
This can be very useful for exaple when you whant to implement a sort algortithm! Of course you can also use other Interfaces with where!